# How to disable the click event of child if item is clicked in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick

I have implemented a recycler view where each row has images.
Now when i click on inflated image it open the image.
My requirement is to disable the click of image if we click the item row.
I have implemented;

@Override
 public void onItemClick(View view, int position){
}

But on clicking of item , it takes the click of inflated card as well and open the image.
On click of item i want to perform some other operation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in your adapter

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemsAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_recycler, viewGroup, false);
        return new ItemsAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);


    }


      @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ItemsAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {

            myViewHolder.itemView .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                myViewHolder.yourImage.setEnabled(false);
                 //rest of your code here

                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View viewChild = yourRecyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(yourAdapter.getItemId(position)).itemView;
viewChild.setEnabled(false);
```

This code solved my problem.